# Google maps api revert icon style change

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a map, where on mouseover, the icon being hovered changes style, that's working fine, the problem is when a second marker is hovered, i need the first marker to 'go back' to the original style, but can't find a way to do it.
Here is the code that is currently working, would appreciate a hint on where should i try facing this.
Thanks

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                        var markerGroups = {
                            "Wavelength": [],
                            "Wavelength_100G": [],
                            "Ethernet": [],
                            "IP_Transit": [],
                            "Video": [],
                            "CDN": []
                        };

                        function load() {
                            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                                center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.639104, -8.210413),
                                zoom: 3
                            });
                            //var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();



                            map.set('styles', [{zoomControl: false},
                                {"elementType": "labels", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},
                                {"featureType": "administrative", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},
                                {"featureType": "landscape", "stylers": [{"color": "#0b223a"}]},
                                {"featureType": "poi", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},
                                {"featureType": "road", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},
                                {"featureType": "transit", "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]},
                                {"featureType": "water", "stylers": [{"color": "#0b5ca2"}]}

                            ]);

                            downloadUrl("../markers/points.php", function (data) {
                                //console.log(data);
                                //var xml = xmlParse(data.response);
                                var xml = data.responseXML;
                                var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                                for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                                    //alert(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
                                    var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
                                    var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
                                    var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");

                                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
                                    var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                                    // var icon = customIcons[type] || {};

                                    var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, type, map);
                                    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);


                                }
                            });
                        }
                        function createMarker(point, name, address, type, map) {

                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map,
                                position: point,
                                icon: {
                                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                                    scale: 3,
                                    strokeWeight: 1.5,
                                    strokeColor: "#01B04C",
                                    fillColor: "#0b223a",
                                    fillOpacity: 1.0
                                },
                                // shadow: icon.shadow,
                                type: type,
                            });
                            if (!markerGroups[type])
                                markerGroups[type] = [];
                            markerGroups[type].push(marker);
                            var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
                            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
                            return marker;
                        }

                        function toggleGroup(type) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[type].length; i++) {
                                var marker = markerGroups[type][i];
                                if (!marker.getVisible()) {
                                    marker.setVisible(true);
                                } else {
                                    marker.setVisible(false);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
                            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (markerGroups) {

                                }

                                this.setIcon({
                                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                                    scale: 3,
                                    strokeWeight: 1.5,
                                    strokeColor: "#01B04C",
                                    fillColor: "#F26522",
                                    fillOpacity: 1.0
                                });
                                $("#res").html(html);
                            }
                            );
                        }

                        function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
                            var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                                    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                                    new XMLHttpRequest;

                            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                                    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                                    callback(request, request.status);
                                }
                            };

                            request.open('GET', url, true);
                            request.send(null);
                        }

                        function doNothing() {}
                        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', load);

                        function xmlParse(str) {
                            if (typeof ActiveXObject != 'undefined' && typeof GetObject != 'undefined') {
                                var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
                                doc.loadXML(str);
                                return doc;
                            }

                            if (typeof DOMParser != 'undefined') {
                                return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
                            }

                            return createElement('div', null);
                        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API — Unique Active Icon per marker on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831358/google-maps-api-unique-active-icon-per-marker-on-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to have an variable called `lastHover` and then in the `mouseover` event when you have done the `setIcon` call, set `lastHover` to the the current hovered marker. Then also add a `if` statement to perform a check like `if lastHover marker is set then unset its hovered icon`.

**Example:**

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var lastHovered = null;

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function (markerGroups) {
                if (lastHovered) {
                    // Set back the original icon
                    ...
                }

                // Set current marker with the hover icon
                ...

                // Set current as lastHovered - so we can unset it when a mouseover on a new marker occurs
                lastHovered = marker;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @GustavoBenitoSilva hope this helps, if it doesn't just drop a msg. Happy to discuss a bit more. Just for next time will be even better if you can convert part of your solution into a working JSFiddle so we can also test our solution.