# Change icon of marker clicked when you have multiple markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to change the marker icon when the marker is clicked the problem is the code below only changes the last marker I added to the map not the marker I am clicking on, so if I only had one marker it would work fine. I tried looking it up but all the examples I could find only work with 1 marker loaded in the map. I tried the listener two different ways the second one is commented out below the the first way and both just change the icon of the the last marker loaded.

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 95%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 95%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
 
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    let markers = [];
    let map;

    function loadMarkers(ssStr)
    {
        $.getJSON(ssStr, function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++)
        {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$lat']['$t'], 
            data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$long']['$t']);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:  latLng,
            map: map,
            label:data.feed.entry[i]['gsx$structure']['$t'],
            icon: {      url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png"          }
            });
            
        markers.push(marker);   
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            //Change the marker icon
            marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png');
            }); 

    /*  marker.addListener("click", (event) => {
        marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png');
        }); */
        }   
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$lat']['$t'], 
            data.feed.entry[0]['gsx$long']['$t']);
        map.setCenter(latLng);

        }); 
    }

    function initMap() {
        console.log("initMap");
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.5, -72)
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);  
        
        loadMarkers("http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/SSID/od6/public/values?alt=json");

    }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers).

Comment: related question: [Change Google Maps marker icon when clicking on other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754101/change-google-maps-marker-icon-when-clicking-on-other)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API — Unique Active Icon per marker on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831358/google-maps-api-unique-active-icon-per-marker-on-click)

Comment: Try `this.setIcon(...)` in the click event function to changed the icon of the marker that was clicked.

Comment: If I add this.setIcon(...) I get  "Cannot read property 'setIcon' of undefined"

Comment: It works for me (if I create a [mcve] from the posted code with markers from [this google example](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex#maps_icon_complex-javascript)).  Second request, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.